# Which function is better in order to find the largest integer variable between three variables

Tags: java, if-statement

I was wondering which function is better in order to find the largest variable between three variables. From what I see the first one has less instructions. Nevermind if we add more variables.

## Function 1

```
 public static void  printLargest(int a, int b, int c)
    {
            if(a > b && a > c)
                System.out.println("a");
            else if(b > a && b > c)
                System.out.println("b");
            else 
                System.out.println("c");
    }
```

## Function 2

```
public static void printLargest(int a, int b, int c)
    {
        if( a > b)
        {
            if(a < c)
                System.out.println("C");
            else
                System.out.println("A");
        }
        else
        {
            if(b < c)
                System.out.println("C");
            else
                System.out.println("B");
        }
    }
```

Comment: better in terms of what? code readability, number of lines of code?

Comment: **number of lines of code** and **code readability**.

Comment: If you have a lot of variables (numbers) to compare... that could get to be a very messy if statement... I would recommend putting the numbers into an Array and then sort the array...

Comment: It's a general practice to avoid nesting if you can. So I would say function 1 is better. Also, you don't have a scenario in which the values are equal.

Comment: You could also just use Math.max(a, Math.max(b, c)) to find the largest, have the function return this number, and then System.out.println(result).

Comment: I would personally prefer Function 1 between the two, more lines of code induce more chances of all sorts of problems, missing a semi colon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Function 2 perform fewer compares on average, but it is much harder to read and it duplicates the code for the case where `c` is the largest number. Therefore, I strongly favor Function 1.

You should change the comparisons to >=, though. Otherwise, if `a` and `b` are both 3 and `c` is 2, then it would answer `c` which is probably not what you would want.

Answer (score 2):

Interms of **number of lines of code and code readability** the below 2 lines will dothe required function and give you answer

```
int larg = a>b ? a : b;
int larg2 = larg>c ? larg : c;   

 System.out.println("\nLargest among numbers " +  a +", "+ b + " and "+ c + " is : " + larg2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not try recursion for simpler and cleaner approach.

```
System.out.println("Greatest is :"+findLargest(findLargest(a,b),c));

public static int findLargest(int a, int b){
if(a>b)
    return a;
else
    return b;
}
```

PS: Sorry for formatting as I am on my mobile.